# jQuery Event Callback Speed: Anonymous vs. Named Functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, jquery-events, jsperf

This is kind of a random question, but I was wondering why a named callback was performing worse, for a click event, relative to an anonymous function.

Here is the link to the [JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/jquery-events-anonymous-vs-named-callbacks) tests I ran in Firefox and Chrome on Mac.

I guess my assumption was that named callbacks would always perform better. For instance, when using `.each` the named callback [is slightly faster](http://jsperf.com/jquery-iterator-anonymous-vs-named).

Thanks for your time!

**Edit** I edited the `.each` JSPerf test because (a) I wasn't testing what I meant and (b) I'm *trying* to mimic events more so.

**Edit 2** My test setup was incorrect from the start as @Esailija points out below. This question is somewhat pointless but at least it might help someone with JSPerf testing.

Comment: Your jsperf with `.each` is not a good test, since the anonymous function has to be created and passed during each iteration, but the named function does not need to be created during each iteration.

Comment: I understand that. I was just using it as a comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jsperf is broken because you accumulate event handlers across test boundaries. In other wrods, whatever test is run first will be the "fastest".

And the whole premise of the test is ridiculous, there is no difference between a function that has a name and a function that doesn't have a name if everything else is equal. You will only see a difference when you are setting up jsperf incorrectly. When you constantly get equal results for them then you know that you set it up correctly - but you would know this already from common sense :)

Comment: How do I avoid accumulating event handlers across test boundaries? Would I do that by calling the `.off` method in the teardown as @Kavun suggested? I do see what you mean, however, by the fastest being the one that's run first. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @doubleswirve Technically you don't even need jQuery since you are measuring function call speed. But attaching event handler just once outside tests like this works too: http://jsperf.com/jquery-events-anonymous-vs-named-callbacks/4

Comment: Ohhh I got it. Sorry for the confusion and thanks for your patience. I was definitely not testing what I intended. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The anonymous function is passed as an argument, so to resolve its reference, the scope chain does not reach all the way back to the parent function that created it - it only exists as an argument. On the other hand, to resolve the reference to the named function, the scope chain is followed all the way back to the parent function closure where the named function was created.

**Edit:**
I tried to prove this, but it seems as if the anonymous function does not actually get resolved faster - http://jsperf.com/scope-chain-anonymous-function

**Edit:** If you call `a.off();` to remove any event handlers, the named function will be just as fast or faster than resolving the anonymous function.

- http://jsperf.com/jquery-events-anonymous-vs-named-callbacks/2
- http://jsperf.com/jquery-event-callback-nested/2

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does your answer relate to this at all: http://jsperf.com/jquery-event-callback-nested. I might be confusing myself but I figured `cb_d` would have been the fastest.

Comment: I would have thought that too.

Comment: Removing the event handlers first with `$.fn.off()` seems to resolve that.

Comment: But would that ever actually be a use case?

Comment: When building components that may be reinitialized, it is best to remove any old event handlers before attaching new ones ie: `$(el).off('click.EventNamespace').on('click.EventNamespace', function () {});`